# Failover api servers cluster with zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I hava a cluster of api servers ,and I want to use zookeeper to implement their automatic failover ,is there sample code for this ?
And i am wondering that after api server connect and register themself to zookeeper,who need to (or who is responsible to) monitor their connection  state,  the zookeeper or the api servers?
And what is the scenario being called *fail* then to start the failover procedure?

Comment: Have you looked at Curator?  Curator is a library built on Zookeeper which covers the most common use cases for Zookeeper.  https://curator.apache.org/